# Calculate $\int\!\!\int (3x+4y) \, dy\, dx $ over the triangle with vertices $(0,0)$, $(3,3)$, and $(0,5)$.

Tags: integration

Calculate the double integral
$$\iint_T (3x+4y) \text{ } dy\text{ } dx $$over the triangle, $T$, with vertices $(0, 0)$,  $(3, 3)$, and $(0, 5)$. I just need help with working out the limits

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the picture here: http://flockdraw.com/gallery/view/1984098

you will see that your triangle is made up of the three lines $x=0$, $y=f(x)$, $y=g(x)$. You should figure out what $f$ and $g$ are. Because of this, a vertical slice $x=c$ through the triangle covers the $y$ range $[f(c),g(c)]$. The overall $x$ range is $0$ to $3$. So your integral is

$$\int_0^3 \int_{f(x)}^{g(x)} (3x+4y) dy dx$$

where $f$ and $g$ are as in my sketch above.

Alternately, you can work with horizontal slices. This is harder, basically because the upper limit in the $x$ range turns around, but it still works. Here's another picture for this case: http://flockdraw.com/gallery/view/1984099. When we slice through with $y=c$ and $c>3$, the figure shows that the $x$ range is between $0$ and $h(c)$. With $c<3$ the $x$ range is between $0$ and $j(c)$. The overall $y$ range is $0$ to $5$. So your integral is also

$$\int_0^3 \int_{0}^{j(y)} (3x+4y) dx dy + \int_3^5 \int_0^{h(y)} (3x+4y) dx dy$$

where $h$ and $j$ are as in my sketch above.

Answer (score 1):

One of the edges of your triangle is aligned with the $y$ axis. I suggest looking at vertical slices of your triangle and what linear functions describe how their upper and lower endpoints change with $x$. That is, you know that the upper endpoint changes from $y=5$ to $y=$ as $x$ goes from $0$ to $3$. Likewise the lower endpoint goes from $0$ to $3$ in this interval.

This will give you integration in $y$ with limits a function of $x$, then integrating in $x$ from $0$ to $3$ will give you your result.

Comment: im still unsure what my limits are, so my x limits are 0 to 3. Is f2(x)= 3 because m2 is -2/3 and c2 is 5? And is m2=1 and c1=0 so that f1(x)=x?

Comment: Your lower limit in $y$ should be $x$ and your upper limit $5 - \frac{2}{3}x$, as these are the equations describing the edges of the triangle. Integrate vertically in $y$, i.e. $\int_{x}^{5-\frac{2}{3}x} (\cdots)\mathrm{d}y$, and then horizontally, $\int_{0}^{3} (\cdots) \mathrm{d}x$ in $x$

Answer (score 0):

You will need to split this up into two integrals.  Suppose, $f_1(x)=m_1x+b_1$ is the equation of the line through $(0,0)$ and $(3,3)$, and $f_2(x)=m_2x+b_2$ is the equation of the line
through $(3,3)$ and $(0,5)$ then

$$\iint(3x+4y)\,dydx=\int_0^3\int_{y=f_1(x)}^3(3x+4y)\,dydx+\int_0^3\int_3^{y=f_2(x)}(3x+4y)\,dydx.$$

Comment: Yes, I suggest drawing the region of integration, then splitting it along the line $y=3$.

Comment: i got 139.5, would it be possible to tell me if that's right or not?

Comment: @NeedHelp2015 You should get 102.5 at the end.

Comment: Why break it into two integrals?  I can see the use if you were integrating with respect to $x$ first, but in this answer there is no apparent reason.

Comment: @Jonas You're right. I'm a little rusty. You certainty could do $\int_0^3\int_{y=f_1(x)}^{y=f_2(x)}(3x+4y)\,dydx $.